# Is there an easy way to capture the error code (%errorlevel%) from a nested batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a nested batch script and I want my error codes from it to percolate up to the main batch script that called it. I have tried

```
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

but the variable doesn't make it back. ECHO'ing %errorlevel% in the called batch script gives me 103, but ECHO'ing %errorlevel% in the main batch script (the very next line in terms of execution) gives me 0. This question has been asked on SO before, but none of the posts have worked for me.

EDIT: Due to poor writing, I have revised my question and also will add the code for you to see.

Here is the main batch file. The if statement here is never hit unless I change the condition to something other than 0:

```
call BuildInstaller.cmd %SourceDir% %TargetDir% %ProductVersion% %%I
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    ECHO %date% %time%: Build of %%I failed, halting >> %LOGFILE%
    exit /b %errorlevel%
)
```

Here is where BuildInstaller.cmd exits. I have cleaned up the prints to avoid confusion:

```
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    exit /b %errorlevel%
)
```

As a side note, I also tried doing

```
set returnvalue=12
```

in the called batch script, but ECHO'ing %returnvalue% in the main batch script was always one execution of the program behind. If anyone knows the answer to this sub-question, that would be cool to know.

Comment: Actually you do not need the if  at the bottom of `BuildInstaller.cmd` the `errorlevel` is already set and your calling batch will operate correctly.  Refer to my example in answer below.

Comment: The if statement is there because that isn't the end of the file. That code is in the middle in order to halt execution if candle.exe fails. I will be happy to post much bigger portions of the batch files if that will help.

Comment: Ok I see, my mistake I thought it was the last lines in the batch.  Your if statement is correct.

Comment: I just took your code as posted and put inside two batch files and it passes back the errorlevel as expected.  There is something else going on.

Comment: Alright, I will set up a bare-bones script set and try it myself and post the results here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the classical Delayed Expansion error. See this example:

```
call BuildInstaller.cmd %SourceDir% %TargetDir% %ProductVersion% %%I
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    ECHO %date% %time%: Build of %%I failed, halting >> %LOGFILE%
    exit /b %errorlevel%
)
```

This is BuildInstaller.cmd:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if 1 == 1 (
   rem Inside a code block, %errorlevel% have the same value it had before the block
   rem (its %value% is NOT updated inside the block) so you need to use !errorlevel!
   rem in order to get the *updated* value

   verify set errorlevel = 1
   if !errorlevel! neq 0 (
      exit /b !errorlevel!
   )
)

exit /B
```

For further details, look for "Delayed Expansion".

Comment: Yes - we know it is a delayed expansion issue because of this quote *"As a side note, I also tried doing `set returnvalue=12` in the called batch script, but ECHO'ing %returnvalue% in the main batch script was always one execution of the program behind."* But we don't really know if the problem is in the main script or the called script.

Comment: @dbenham: I think that the fact that the problem is in `BuildInstaller.cmd` is clear enough. Comment: _"Actually you do not need the if at the bottom of `BuildInstaller.cmd`..."_ Reply: _"The if statement is there because that isn't the end of the file. That code is in the middle in order to halt execution if candle.exe fails"_ I just assumed that "in the middle" imply "inside a block".

Comment: *"I just assumed..."* Like I said, we don't really know :-) BTW - I already upvoted

Comment: That fixed it! In the main batch, file I added SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion and changed the error check after calling the batch scripts from %errorlevel% to !errorlevel! and everything is working perfectly. I didn't have to change anything other than the main script. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The errorlevel is set after each command has been executed.  So the error level of 0 is the result of the statement after the one that created error level 103.

To illustrate with multiple batch files:

sub.bat:

```
 rem This is invalid argument for zip which sets errorlevel
 zip -QQ
```

test.bat:

```
 @echo off
 call sub.bat
 echo %errorlevel%
```

Example output which the first line comes from zip:

```
zip error: Invalid command arguments (no such option: Q)
16
```

Comment: I removed the if statement from my called batch file and had it just straight exit directly after the failing candle call (I am having it fail intentionally), but the if statement in the main batch script still got passed over.